# How do I easily convert an iterative solution to a recursive solution?

Tags: python, recursion, stack

I was practicing an interview question of converting a BST into a doubly-LinkedList.

The tree:

[image]

will become

[image]

The method that I used was to use a stack and do some pointer manipulation while traversing the tree in in-order.

Below is my code:

```
def treeToDoublyList(self, root):
    """
    :type root: Node
    :rtype: Node
    """

    if not root:
        return

    dummy = Node(-1, None, None)
    prev = dummy
    stack = []
    n = root
    while stack or n:
        while n:
            stack.append(n)
            n = n.left
        n = stack.pop()
        n.left = prev
        prev.right = n
        prev = n
        n = n.right
    dummy.right.left = prev
    prev.right = dummy.right
    return dummy.right
```

I like solving this kind of problem iteratively because it's very intuitive. But in most cases, I will also be asked to implement a recursive solution. I know the data structure stack resembles how recursive functions behave, but I am still having difficulties in converting an iterative one to a recursive one. Any tips?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: One thing I don't like your solution is that it merges your breadth first search code with your linked list code. What if you want to use breadth first search to make an array? Or you want to make a linked list, but using depth first search instead? You haven't done a good job modularizing these 2 otherwise unrelated aspects of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually every recursive function can be designed around a "base case" and a "recursive case".

- The base case might be a single node, with no children: this yields a trivial doubly-linked list of one element.
- In the recursive case, you need to build the list for the left child (if any), then the current node, and then finally the right child.

Now you need a way to combine the results. You can either:

- pass a (initially-empty) list into the function, which each operation appends to in-order, or
- construct sub-lists, which then get spliced together in the recursive case.

Which makes more sense depends on the application, but either is valid.

You might want to think about the trade-offs of the different approaches; if I were interviewing you I'd ask about them.

Comment: For the record, a more likely 'base case' might be the absent tree (None, in python) which you deal with by doing nothing. Then the "recursive" case doesn't have to worry about which children are present/absent.